# Why would one choose to use the finally statement instead of a catch statement? (Java)

Tags: java, exception, try-catch, try-catch-finally

I'm relatively new to `Java` and I'm still trying to understand the fundamentals. I have been learning about exception handling in the form of `try-catch` statements. These are fine and I understand how and why I should make use of them. The thing that has confused me is the `try-finally` statements.

To be more specific I don't see why I can't just use a `catch` statement to do the same thing. What is the benefit of choosing to put some commands in a `finally` statement as opposed to putting the same statements in the `catch` statement? Won't the statements still be executed in exactly the same way?

Sorry if this is a silly or naive question. I just can't quite work out the benefits of using the `finally` statement.

Comment: Hmm this should give you all the information you need: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/finally.html

Comment: There's no 'instead of' about it. They do different things for different purposes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`catch` : When something goes wrong.
`finally` : When something / nothing goes wrong.
Like if you want to close database connection irrespective of whether an exception is thrown or not, In such case `finally` will be best place to put your code.
Also if you have multiple catch blocks with some redundant code, you can move redundant part to `finally` block.

Comment: Note that this means that in the case of an exception *both* the catch and finally blocks will be executed.

Comment: @AdrianMouat: Yup.The finally block always executes when the try block exits.

Answer (score 4):

The catch statement will not always run. The finally statement is guaranteed to run. Eg: if you need to close a stream.

Comment: But we can close that stream(in your case) outside of try/catch/finally... right?

Answer (score 2):

The `finally` branch is executed regardless of whether an exception has been thrown or not.  The `catch` branches are executed only if the specified exception has been thrown from within the `try` block.

You would use `finally` usually when you want to ensure that a resource has been properly released (e.g. an open file closed) at the and of the `try` block, no matter if the `try` fully succeeded or not - this not only ensures that the block of code in the `finally` gets executed if the `try` block succeeds or if any of the `catch` branches are executed, but also when an exception not listed in the `catch` blocks is thrown (e.g. an unchecked exception or runtime error)

Comment: +1: "also when an exception not listed in the catch blocks is thrown", is the important case to point out

Answer (score 2):

```
try {
    //...
} catch(SomeException ex) {
    //code to execute if exception occurs
} finally {
    //code to execute no matter whether the exception occured or not
    //usually you put code to close resources here so that in any condition the
    //resources are released back to the system
}
```

Comment: Really the same as the answer jacknad gave, but +1 for a code style presentation.

Answer (score 1):

The finally block **is always executed**, if an exception occurs or not. Whereas the catch block will be executed **only if a *catchable exception* occurs or is thrown**.

An exception is "*catchable*" if its class match (one of) the definition made in the catch statement. For exampe :

`catch(AnException ex | AnOtherException ex2) {}`

Will only catch exception of type `AnException` or `AnOtherException` *(Note that it's JSE7 typo)*.

I suggest you to read the JSL about the execution order of the [**`try-catch-finally statement`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.2), it contains all details.

Note that `finally` is often use to release ressource (ie use the `close()` method) since JDK7 you can use the [try-with-ressource](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/trywithresources-401775.html) [statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) that will automatically close ressource for you, it works for class that implement [AutoCloseable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html).

Comment: But we can even do cleanup outside of try/catch/finally... right?

Answer (score 0):

*Try* is for *Catch(Exception e)* a specific exception and execute a *finally* statement.